# Which article, if any, is the best choice in this case?

Tags: grammar, articles

I work in IT and have a question about using articles in the following sentence:

> *There is ____ AllowedChanges table with ____ 
>    AllowedPctType column in the database.*

So my question is which article, if there is any, is appropriate here and why?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Depends on the context and narrative. All three are possible.

Comment: A more useful Question there would be what you meant by "There is ____ AllowedChanges table with ____ AllowedPctType column in the database", don't you think?

If you could translate that into clear English, what Question would there still be?

If not, why does it belong here, rather than on a site dealing with whatever programming language you used to control your database?

Comment: My question only applies to English grammar, not to my professional field or anything else. This example was taken only because I had encountered it in my work, and I didn't want to waste time looking for an example from another professional field.

Answer (score -1):

You need "the" in both cases, because you are referring to specific things that only one of them exists in the database (one AllowedChanges table and one AllowedPctType column).